# Is there a difference between Pin<Box<T>> and Box<Pin<T>>?

Tags: rust

In Rust, are there any functional differences between `Pin<Box<T>>` and `Box<Pin<T>>`? I think that they should behave the same, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Pin<Box<T>>` is what you want. `Box<Pin<T>>` will not work at all.

`Pin` requires its type to be a pointer of  some kind. It then prevents you from moving out of this pointer (if the pointee isn't `Unpin`), by requiring `unsafe` to access it mutably. In `Pin<Box<T>>` `Box<T>` is the pointer. It is common because you can create it safely (as opposed to `Pin<&mut T>` that without macros can only be created unsafely) because you give the ownership of the  `Box` to it, and thus you cannot access the inner `T` not through the `Pin`. `Box<Pin<T>>`, on the other hand, is useless: it is impossible to create if `T` does not implement `Deref` (as `Pin`'s constructors require that, because they are meant to use with pointers) and even if `T` does, the `Box` is redundant: you already have a pointer, there is no need to wrap it in `Box`. In addition, you cannot create an instance of `Box<Pin<T>>` if the `<T as Deref>::Target` does not implement `Unpin` without unsafe code, and there is little benefit in `Pin` with `Unpin` types (it can be passed to APIs that require it, such as `Future::poll()`, but in that case you don't need the `Box`).